# React.js: display time from timer using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display the time left before next email resend is available. Basically my implementation works, but it looks really ugly to me and I wonder if there is (I'm sure there must be) a better way to do it.

My code:

```js
function ResetPasswordPage(props) {
    
    // ...

    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(0);
    const [timeStart, setTimeStart] = React.useState(props.resendIn);
    const [timerTrigger, setTimerTrigger] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let tleft = props.resendIn || timeStart;
        setTimeLeft(tleft);

        if (tleft > 0) {
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                if (tleft <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
                else{
                    tleft--;
                    setTimeLeft(prev => prev - 1)
                }
            }, 1000)
            
            return () => {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }

    }, [props.resendIn, timeStart, timerTrigger]);

    const handleSubmit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ...

        setTimeStart(60);
        setTimerTrigger(t => !t);
    }

    return (
        <>
        {
            //...
            <p>{timeLeft}</p>
        }
        </>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // ...
    resendIn: state.resetPasswordReducer.resendIn
})
// export
```

The main question is why if I use `timeLeft` inside `setInterval` it's not being changed after I do `setTimeLeft(prev => prev - 1)`?

As you can see my approach is to

1. use a "buffer" variable to monitor the remaining time and a separate `timeLeft` variable to display the time.
2. use a separate `timeTrigger` just to make effect callback be called.
3. server doesn't return remaining time on successful request, so I need `timeStart` to be 60 by default and start the countdown immediately after form submit.

Could anybody advice how to improve this code?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the exact left time. I had cases where the interval time is not precise. In order to understand we need to keep in mind a fact that javascript is essentially single threaded, meaning it will not perform more than one operation at a time. We will find that  setInterval breaks it's rhythm.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      let tleft = props.resendIn || timeStart;
      let time = Date.now();

      setTimeLeft(tleft);

      if (tleft > 0) {
          const timer = setInterval(() => {
            const current = Date.now();
            const timeLeft = Math.floor((current - time) / 1000);
              if (timeLeft > tleft) {
                  clearInterval(timer);
              }
              else{
                  setTimeLeft(tleft - timeLeft)
              }
          }, 1000)
          
          return () => {
              clearInterval(timer);
          }
      }

  }, [props.resendIn, timeStart, timerTrigger]);
```